# Simple animation in Python using wxPython objects

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I'm writing a gravity simulator in Python 2.7 and at the moment I finished the mathematical part. I'm trying to find a way to display the results while the simulation is running, it should consist of some colored circles representing the various bodies and optionally some curved lines to represent orbits, that can be shown or hidden while the simulation is running.

I pictured a way to obtain this result, but I can't seem to find a way to even start.

My idea is to use wxPython. The window should be divided into four sectors (2x2), the first three contain the simulation viewed in the XY, XZ and YZ planes, while the last contains the controls (start/stop simulation, show/hide orbits, ...).

The controls should not be a problem, I just need a way to display the animation. So how can I display moving circles and curved lines using wxPython objects? Which objects should I use? I don't need much more than a couple names, the rest should follow easily.

I know that an animation purely with wxPython will probably require some multithreading, I'm already prepared for that. I also want to stress that I need the animation to be shown **while** the simulation is running, not after, because the simulation has no definite end at the moment: I don't know when to stop it if I don't see the results first.

If it's somehow useful, I'm using Ubuntu Linux 17.10.

Edit: Since I was asked to choose one approach, I discarded Matplotlib because it requires two different windows. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a task, not a problem. Also it is much too broad for this Q&A format (essentially you're asking for someone to do your work). So, since both directions are possible, decide for one first. Attempt a solution and if you encounter a problem, ask about the problem using a [mcve] (i.e. runnable code).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I'm not asking for a complete solution, but just what object and/or functions I should use. I can do the rest, but right now I don't really know where to start. And the broadness of the question come from that problem, and also from the fact that I don't know which one is better.

Comment: There are no criteria for "better" in the question and even if there were it would be highly subjective what "better" is. I think you're looking at this from the wrong end. If you don't want to decide for one solution, you need to implement both and see what suits you more. But start with small steps: Find out what graphics you can paint in wx, paint a circle, try to let that circle move. Do the same in matplotlib. Until that point completely forget about planets and buttons etc. Ask a question about the road blocker, not the final product.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest "Better" means simply "easier to implement". If I have to write 10 times more code for one solution than for the other to obtain the same result, the second is better than the first. And the road blocker is exactly the fact that I don't know how to start, I can't find the adequate object in the wxPython documentation to draw a movable shape, nor can I find a way in Matplotlib to have an updatable plot. The rest is fairly easy, I'm confident enough in my programming and math skills to skip the small steps and go straight to the final result.

Comment: Sorry, but the start is of course to google something like "animate circle wxpython".

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Yes, that was like a month ago.